# Mutated vowels (in german: "Umlaute") in Aptana 3 terminal

Tags: console, terminal, aptana, diacritics

I use Aptana Studio 3 for rails development together with git versioning. In my commit messages I'd like to use mutated vowels (Umlaute). In Terminal (Mac OSX) everything works fine, but in the Aptana terminal I get strange characters (btw: in the Aptana editors mutated vowels work). Is there a way to get this working?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Aptana Studio 3.0.2 release.